# polarcoordinate and just straight evaluation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate  $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 xy(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ dy\ dx$.

I started off using polar coordinate and then im stuck with defining the bound. And how would you solve it without polar coordinates

Comment: You need to identify the region.

Comment: sorry 0 to 1 for each x and y. Thanjs

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  We will integrate first with respect to $y$, and then with respect to $x$. So for a while $x$ is **fixed**.

Let $x^2+y^2=u$. Then $2y\,dy=du$ so $y\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\,du$. The inner integral is 
$$\int_{x^2}^{1+x^2} \frac{1}{2}x u^{1/2}\,du.$$

The outer integral (integration with respect to $x$) can also be done by substitution.

Polar coordinates also work nicely. We are integrating on the unit square. It will be useful to split into two parts, $\theta=0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ annd $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Use symmetry to cut the work in half. For the bounds on the first integral, note that the line $x=1$ has polar equation $r\cos\theta=1$.